# how to change default network adapter

Tags: networking, pi-4, linux, kali

i recently bought a external network adapter (alfa awus036AXML ) and wanna use with my Raspberri pi 4 type b.i installed Kali Linux on my Raspberri pi.
can you help me please?
i installed the Drivers but i cant disable default network adapter wlan0 in my Device and change it to my Mediatek chipset ALFA
Thanks

Comment: [Kali](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @Milliways - brutal, but so true